# float.Parse fails on decimals and commas

Tags: c#, parsing

When I try this line:

```
float f = float.Parse(val, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```

where val is a string set to "5.267" without the quotes, I get this error:

FormatException: Unknown char: .
System.Double.Parse (System.String s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider)
System.Single.Parse (System.String s, NumberStyles style)

So I tried changing the decimal point to a comma, like:  5,267  and got this error:

FormatException: Unknown char: ,
System.Double.Parse (System.String s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider)
System.Single.Parse (System.String s, NumberStyles style)

I....don't....understand.  As far as I can tell I'm doing this right.  It's a simple thing, so why is it giving me such grief?

Comment: Why not just do `float.Parse(yourValue);`? I just ran it and got no errors with commas or the decimal point

Comment: `NumberStyles.Any` works fine for me, have you tried?

Comment: Is it possible that neither `.` nor `,` are the decimal point or thousands separator in your current culture?

Comment: @TimGoodman I dunno why, but it seems like that. I had the same problem as damocles. It wouldn't parse with decimal point when I used CurrentCulture..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Parse is culture aware.  If your local culture has different requirements, then you may want to pass a culture or other format provider in.  Try using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.  You won't need the decimal option if you do.

```
float f = float.Parse(val,
                      System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands,
                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: That's the one - I needed InvariantCulture.  Thanks Matt.

Comment: This is the answer what I've been looking for! Thx!

Comment: Dude if I'm coding IN ENGLISH I use english '.' for decimals not european ',' but thanks mate your answer was the best

Comment: @Squareroot - It's not about the language you are coding in.  It's about the language the contents of the string is interpreted in.  You might be writing C# using English keywords and periods to denote decimals in literals, but that doesn't mean your user's are necessarily English speaking.  Also, in real life it's not just about language as to which separators are used, but also location.  See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DecimalPoint.html

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var numList = new List<string>(){"0", "-6e-5", "78.56238", "05.56", "0.5E9", "-45,000.56", "", ".56", "10.4852,64"};
            numList.ForEach(num =>
            {
                // If we use NumberStyles.Float => -45,000.56 is invalid
                if (decimal.TryParse(num, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out decimal result))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(num + " is not a valid number");
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to explain more clearly why this is an answer to the question.