# Why does comma (",") disappear when converting string to float in c#.

Tags: c#, winforms, parsing

Currently I am doing this way.

```
string strPoint = "12.5";
string strComma = "12,5";

Console.WriteLine("strPoint: " + float.Parse(strPoint,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

Console.WriteLine("strComma: " + float.Parse(strComma,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

**Result:**
`strPoint: 12,5` and `strComma: 125`.

`strComma` must be `12.5`? what could be the reason behind this. Please advise.

Comment: It is probably a localisation / culture issue. Your PC is currently set to a culture that interprets a dot as a decimal but does not see a comma this way. The issue is the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture (probably)

Comment: possible duplicate of [float.Parse fails on decimals and commas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941476/float-parse-fails-on-decimals-and-commas)

Comment: @RobSmyth Both versions use `InvariantCulture`, so it's independent of the PC settings.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `InvariantCulture` from second Parse.Use your current culture.The decimal separator of `InvariantCulture` is *dot*,not *comma*.You can verify that using :

```
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator;
```

In first code snippet you are using *dot* as a separator and using the `InvariantCulture` for Parse and it is parsing correctly because the InvariantCulture uses dot as a separator.

In the second code snippet you are using *comma* and it is truncated because it is not the decimal separator of `InvariantCulture`, the same culture can not use two different separators at the same time.

Comment: Nothing is getting truncated. Truncating would turn "12,5" into 12, but it is getting turned into 125.

Comment: the end user can write either **,** or **.** in a TextBox
<br>
my code:
`return float.Parse(prix,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`
How can rewrite my code?
@Selman22 @hvd @RobSmyth

Answer (score 1):

In `InvariantCulture`, the comma is the thousands separator, and for correct strings, the result of parsing cannot depend on whether the thousands separator is present (1000 and 1,000 are two different representations of the same number). `float.Parse`, however, does not enforce that the thousands separator is only used in the appropriate places, it simply skips it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I think "fLoat.parse()" will treat "," as a group separator not as decimal separator which is "."
Hence Group separator in this case will always be vanish in output mentioned.